# how to add a number with filter return value in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I used this filter and getting desired output but in my case how to add a value to that filter.

My filter:

```
angular
    .module('Test', [])
    .filter('sumByColumn', function () {
      return function (collection, column) {
        var total = 0;

        collection.forEach(function (item) {
          total += parseInt(item[column]);
        });

        return total;
      };
    });
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7b3q2q5p/4/

For example if i have a `$scope.a = 5` then i have to add with the filter value in (fiddle example) like `{{ test.approve | sumByColumn: 'amount' }} + {{a}}` .

**`{{ test.approve | sumByColumn: 'amount' }} = 5` then `$scope.a = 5` = `10`** .

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
{{ (test.approve | sumByColumn: 'amount') + a }}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7b3q2q5p/9/

Comment: it worked ., i will mark ., but i want to know how to find the `filter value` is greater then `a` or not ?

Comment: What do you mean ? what you gonna do if filter value is greater ?

Comment: a simple validation message in ng-if

Comment: just use the same filter again in any place you want